# Program Installer Not Detecting Internet

Tags: installation, software-center, internet

Hello I am trying to install a program through the Ubuntu Software Center. Every time I click install I get a Message stating "failed to download package files, check your Internet connection".

I have tried different software installs and get the same message. I do have an Internet connection (hence being able to write this), I have restarted the computer and have reset the Internet (twice) but still get the same message. Any Ideas??

Comment: Do you use network manager to connect to the internet?

Comment: I don't think so. I have the double arrow next to my name at the top right of my screen with a drop list saying "Wired Connection 1" etc...and it says that i am connected. Is there somewhere else I should check under system settings? Many thanks-k

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that source of which the file is to be downloaded from is down.

If this happens to all the software in Ubuntu Software Center, then possibly the Software Sources have been modified? (System Settings / Software Sources) Make sure the sources you want are checked.

ALSO: I remember playing with proxy's and not realized that I had added one to the Settings...  XD

Comment: Thank you very much! I did see that I had program updates that needed to be performed and I am running the updates now and it should hopefully help.